# What is an interval in d3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Looking at the implementation of the `nice` function in the [d3 library](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale/blob/main/src/nice.js#LL1C1-L18C2), I see that `interval` is passed in as a parameter and we call `interval.floor` and `interval.ceiling` on whatever `interval` is.

What exactly is `interval` here? I thought that in d3, `interval` was a function that essentially replicates JavaScript's `timer`.

I've tried searching for `d3 interval` but can only find information about its `interval` function.

Comment: the source code for interval is here: https://github.com/d3/d3-time/blob/v3.1.0/src/interval.js